# NTFS files with 0 size, filestamp 01/01/1970 and "?" at the beginning of file name not deletable

Tags: linux, file-format

I tried to backup millions of files from ext4 to an external NTFS drive. It took ages and at the end gave up, the external drive stalled. After a reboot and successful ntfsfix command I wanted to delete the approx. 10GB from the 17GB it should backup. However, 1.4GB stayed on the external NTFS drive, with folders and files not deletable. What's more, there are thousands of files now with the same strange characteristics, see here:

- filename starts with question mark (e.g. ?1000690.png
- all of those files have 0 size
- all of those files have timestamp 01/01/1970

How can I delete those files? I can't delete the rest of those 1.4GB at the moment and try a new complete backup.